# Auto-modify JSON data and save on build

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

I have a JSON that's with very long list of data and I need to add hard code IDs (statically). I am wondering how I can do this, in a tool like gulp for example, automatically when running a process? I'd like it to give the task a file and modify its contents (as shown below) and then permanently save that file with the updated data.

This is what the data looks like, for example: -

```
[
  {
    "title": "Lorem ipsum",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
  },
  {
    "title": "Maecenas ac elit",
    "text": "Maecenas ac elit vitae lorem interdum tincidunt"
  }
]
```

And here is what I'm looking for in return: -

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "title": "Maecenas ac elit",
    "text": "Maecenas ac elit vitae lorem interdum tincidunt"
  }
]
```

Comment: What context are you using this JSON in? Does it need permanently saving somewhere if you're using gulp?

Comment: @OwenAyres, yes I am saving these data permanently, which in future  again I get the same data and I need to add IDs again statically :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and the index incremented for the `id` property.

```js
var array = [{ "title": "Lorem ipsum", "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" }, { "title": "Maecenas ac elit", "text": "Maecenas ac elit vitae lorem interdum tincidunt" }];

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.id = (i + 1).toString();
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Getting Id's are added now :) can the numbers added in strings ("2") and moved above "title" ?

Comment: string is no problem. but objects have (until es6) no order. if you like to change the orde, then every n object must rebuild in wanted order. i do not recommend that.

Comment: when you have time can you please tell me what 0 & 4 is doing (array, 0, 4) ?

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON objects ID's assigned by sorting order then no need to double the loop , use index+1

for example : http://json.live/173fqW

```
var arr = [{},{},{},{}];

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
{
    var obj = arr[i];
    var id = i+1; //<<-- this is the ID ( array stars from 0 we added +1 to start from 1
}
```